# support for Calendar in SuperCSV

Tags: java, csv, calendar, supercsv

I have a CSV file in this format `RES,2016-02-23_18:01:27` and I want to map the values to a bean which has `String` and `Calendar` type attributes. While writing the cell processor method, there is method to parse the value into `Date` as `ParseDate()`. Here this results in an error as the parser is returning `Date` object and I have `Calendar` object in my bean.

To overcome this, I have created an overloaded setter method in my bean as below:

```
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = new GregorianCalendar();
    this.date.setTime(date);
}
```

Here is my `CellParser` method:

```
private static CellProcessor[] getProcessors() {
    final CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[] { 
         new StrRegEx("\\w{3}"), // string value check
         new ParseDate("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss"), // date
    };
    return processors;
}
```

Is there any native support. I looked at the official site and it's examples. Couldn't able to find references related to `Calendar`. If there is no native support from SuperCSV, is this is best way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to write your own [custom cell processor](http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/examples_new_cell_processor.html).

For example, you can chain the following processor after `ParseDate` to convert it to a `Calendar`.

```
public class DateToCalendar extends CellProcessorAdaptor implements DateCellProcessor {

    public DateToCalendar() {
    }

    public DateToCalendar(final CellProcessor next) {
        super(next);
    }

    public Object execute(final Object value, final CsvContext context) {
        validateInputNotNull(value, context);

        if( !(value instanceof Date) ) {
            throw new SuperCsvCellProcessorException(Date.class, value, context, this);
        }

        Calendar result = Calendar.getInstance();
        result.setTime((Date) value);

        return next.execute(result, context);
    }
}
```

For example,

```
final CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[] { 
         new StrRegEx("\\w{3}"), // string value check
         new ParseDate("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss", new DateToCalendar()) // date
    };
```